# Can I get information if this iPhone connected with Apple watch or not through WatchConnectivity?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I'm making Apple Watch App by Swift. I want to make a function which works depend on the existence of Phone-Watch connection. I'm using WatchConnectivity like below.

```
if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        session = WCSession.default

        session?.delegate = self
        session?.activate()
    }
```

So this iPhone App needs to know if its owner has also this Apple Watch App and it's connected. Can I get that kind of information by Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this information from the `WCSession` object:

```
session.isPaired // true when the iPhone is paired to an Apple Watch
session.isWatchAppInstalled // true when the Watch app associated with the current iOS app is installed on the user’s Apple Watch
```

Be aware that this only works when you activated a `WCSession` on your phone **and** your Watch app